# Git API for open source version

Tags: javascript, git, github, github-api

Is there a git API/rest which I can use to determine open source version?
I mean I'll send the open source name and I'll get the current version of it.

Or better if possible :) Since we are using some open sources in our project I want to create some program/script which provide the open source names and version and find if there is new for minor or major update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is what **[VersionEye](https://www.versioneye.com/)** is doing.

And it has its [own REST API](https://www.versioneye.com/api/)

For example: https://www.versioneye.com/api/v2/products/c/git%2Fgit/versions?api_key=Log+in+to+get+your+own+api+token

Response Body:

```
{
  "name": "git",
  "language": "c",
  "prod_key": "git/git",
  "version": "2.6.4",
  "prod_type": "GitHub",
  "versions": [
    {
      "version": "2.3.0-rc2",
      "released_at": "2015-01-27T22:39:53.000+00:00",
      "released_string": "2015-01-27 22:39:53 UTC"
    },
    {
      "version": "2.3.0-rc1",
      "released_at": "2015-01-21T01:35:41.000+00:00",
      "released_string": "2015-01-21 01:35:41 UTC"
    },
    ...
```

It is actually free for opensource, and [not free for private repos](https://www.versioneye.com/pricing).

It is the only one I know which monitors *all* opensource.
You have other referentials usually dedicated to a language, like for instance [godoc.org](https://godoc.org/-/about) (for the [golang](https://golang.org/) opensource projects), with [its own API](https://github.com/golang/gddo/wiki/API), but limited to a language.

Comment: Thanks 1+ , does it open source and I can use it for free ? and if for example I want to check for express or async where I should put those parameters ?

Comment: @sho I believe you can for a limited number of queries. Past that number, you would need to subscribe a plan.

Comment: So I cannot use it :-( , there is other way to achieve this ? is there is any open source which handle this?

Comment: @shopiaT It is actually free for opensource (you pay only for monitoring private repos) so you can use it. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks! last two questions :) 1. the git doesnt expose those API's which I can use directly ? 2. can you please provide example how should I send a call to find version of express or async ?(please put it in the answer :)

Comment: @shopiaT Can you provide a link for those opensource projects you are seeking the versions for? Those "express" or "sync"? And no, git has nothing to do with those APIs.

Comment: @shopiaT https://www.versioneye.com/api/v2/products/search/express?lang=javascript&api_key=Log+in+to+get+your+own+api+token: you will get the version of express in the body of the json answer.

Comment: @shopiaT even more complete: https://www.versioneye.com/api/v2/products/javascript/strongloop%2Fexpress?api_key=Log+in+to+get+your+own+api+token